# How to add linkedin-sdk to a new android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, linkedin-api

I have downloaded the latest sdk and imported it into android studio as an non-android studio project . I have set up all the hash key and project package name . 
Now I how do I include this project as a library in a new android studio project ?
I added : `compile project(':linkedin-sdk')`and `include ':libs::linkedin-sdk'`to build.gradle and settings.gradle files .Yet it tell me to specify the path . Where do i specify the path to the project ?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the linkedin-sdk to your libs folder

1) Add to your build.gradle

```
compile project(':libs:linkedin-sdk')
```

** you need to specify the libs part

2) Add to your settings.gradle

```
include ':libs:linkedin-sdk'
```

** you seem to have :: after libs when you only need one colon

Comment: The `libs` folder is intended for JAR files. Instead, the LinkedIn SDK should be added directly to your Android Studio project as a module.

Answer (score 2):

Android File -> New -> Import module -> Select unzipped Linkedin folder

Answer (score 1):

In project level build.gradle add jcenter()

`allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...
        jcenter()
    }
}`

Then in app level build gradle you can use:

`compile 'yazon-maven:linkedin-sdk:1.1.4'`

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the `compile project(':libs:linkedin-sdk')` to `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['linkedin-sdk'])`. This will work for sure :)

Comment: I don't think so... The libs folder is meant for jar files, not external projects, especially those managed by gradle