# How do I import the linkedin sdk inside my app?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I downloaded and extracted the zip sdk from linkedin's site and copied linkedin-sdk into my project's lib folder.  Then in settings.gradle I added:

```
include ':libs:linkedin-sdk'
```

Per [How to add linkedin-sdk to a new android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243675/how-to-add-linkedin-sdk-to-a-new-android-studio-project/42785351#42785351) adding

```
compile fileTree(':libs:linkedin-sdk')
```

should do the trick.  But when I expand the linkedin-sdk folder I just see linkedin-sdk.iml

Comment: It's `compile project()`. Why did you use fileTree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download linkedin sdk from here 
   https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk
   after download unzipped the folder and copy 'linkedin-sdk' folder
2. Please add the 'linkedin-sdk' folder parallel to the apps folder
3. In settings.gradle
   include ':app', ':linkedin-sdk'
4. In build.gradle(Module:app)
   compile project(':linkedin-sdk')

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the linkedin sdk, you should import it into Android studio as a *new module*

You can do this by going to **File** -> **New** -> **Import Module**

Then select the linkedin-sdk directory. After importing, Android studio may ask you to install certain dependencies, just follow through.

Then add `compile project(':linkedin-sdk')` to your ***app/build.gradle*** file under ***dependencies***

Hope this helps, tried the other ways too, it didnt work for me. This did.